# Show $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \right )\cong \mathbb{Z}/\left ( n,m \right )\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Show that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \right )\cong \mathbb{Z}/\left ( n,m \right )\mathbb{Z}$

I think that the hom-set (of $\mathbb{Z}$ module homomorphisms ) is isomorphic to $\left \{ a\in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},na=m\mathbb{Z} \right \}=\left \{ k+m\mathbb{Z} \right \}$ where $m\mid (nk)$ but I can't show that it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\left ( n,m \right )\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087986/proof-of-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z-bigotimes-mathbb-z-mathbb-z-m-mathbb-z-cong-h?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/proof-of-mathbbz-m-mathbbz-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $f:\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ be a homomorphism then you can check that
$$0=f(0)=f(n\cdot 1)=nf(1)$$
so $m\mid nf(1)$ and $m/(m,n)\mid f(1)$. Also, $f(1)$ determines whole $f$.

Comment: How are you getting $(m,n) \mid f(1)$?

Comment: @aljebr I was wrong, it should be $m/(m,n)\mid f(1)$

Comment: Got it. So, we have that $f(1)$ must be a multiple of $m/(m,n)$, i.e., $f(1) \in \frac{m}{(m,n)}\mathbb Z$. Can you help me proceed from here?

Comment: More specifically, how do we know that $f(1)$ cannot be a number small than $m/(m,n)$?

Comment: @AlJebr f(1) can be 0, so it can be smaller. The gist of the proof is that multiples of $m/(m,n) \pmod n$ are the only possible values of $f(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

the seq. $Z\to Z\to Z_m \to 0$ is exact, when the 1st homomorphism, $f$ is defined as $f(a)=ma$ and the 2nd, $g$ as $g(x)=\bar x$.
so we have the exact seq.: $$0\to Hom_Z(Z_m,Z_n)\to Hom_Z(Z,Z_n)\to Hom_Z(Z,Z_n)$$ 
here the 1st homomorphism, is $hom(g,1)$ (which is injective map), and the 2nd is $hom(f,1)$.

so $ Hom_Z(Z_m,Z_n)/ker (hom(g,1)) \equiv ker(hom(f,1))$.
now can you prove that $ker(hom(f,1))\equiv Z/\left ( n,m \right )Z$  ?