# Finding all $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphisms $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am pretty sure that it has been already discussed many times, but I couldn't find.

> Well, the problem is to show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)\simeq\mathbb Z/(n,m)\mathbb Z$.

I have proven that $Hom(Z/nZ, Z/mZ)$ is precisely $Ann(nZ) = \{x \in Z/mZ: nx = 0\}. $
Thus my problem reduces to proving $Ann(nZ) = Z/(n,m)Z$, but I haven't gotten success so far.

Comment: When you say "module homomorphisms", do you mean modules over $\Bbb Z$, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left ( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \right )\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong
\mathbb{Z}/\left ( n,m \right )\mathbb{Z},
$$
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087986/proof-of-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z-bigotimes-mathbb-z-mathbb-z-m-mathbb-z-cong-h?rq=1), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/proof-of-mathbbz-m-mathbbz-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d = (n,m)$. Then $m/d$ is relatively prime to $n/d$. Thus, $m$ divides $nx$ if and only if $m/d$ divides $x$. Hence $x = km/d$ for some integer $k$. It follows that $\operatorname{Ann}(n\Bbb Z)$ is the cyclic group generated by $m/d$. The order of $m/d$ in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is $d$.