# Find the kernel of morphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let be $n$ and $m$ two integers such that $m\mid n$.

I want to show that there exists an homomorphism onto between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

I find the homomorphism define by $f(a+n\mathbb{Z})= a+m\mathbb{Z}$. 
Now i want to find it kernel.
So I solve $a+n\mathbb{Z}= m\mathbb{Z}$, but i don't know how to conclude

Comment: Is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072746/finding-all-mathbb-z-module-homomorphisms-mathrmhom-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z any help?

Comment: it is not really the same problem but tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m \mid n$, there exist an integer, M, such that $n = Mm$.

If $a+n\mathbb{Z}= m\mathbb{Z}$, then there are integers, $u$ and $v$, such that

\begin{align}
   a + un &= vm \\
   a &= vm - un \\
   a &= vm - uMm \\
   a &= (v-uM)m \\
   m &\mid a
\end{align}

It follows that 
   $\ker f = \{ 
      0 + \mathbb Z_n, 
      m + \mathbb Z_n,
      2m + \mathbb Z_n,
      \dots,
      (M-1)m + \mathbb Z_n  \}$

Answer (score 2):

Try writing $m\mathbb{Z} = 0 + m\mathbb{Z}$. For an arbitrary abelian group,written additively, $$a + H =b+ H  \iff a-b \in H$$

Also, in the specific case of $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{nZ}$,

$$a + n\mathbb{Z} = b + n\mathbb{Z} \iff n | \space (a-b) \iff a = b + nk \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: i agree your post but i don't understand where do you want to go

Comment: Since $m|n$, $x=y \ mod n \implies x= y \ mod m$